# Privacy policy Issue with two permissions

Tags: android, google-play, privacy-policy

May app has 2 permissions ,i had added them.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

When i uploaded the app to google server they tell me it has 8 permissions

```
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
com.x.x.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
```

I am using Firebase and AdMob.
I am just reading data from Firebase Realtime Database there is no any data store about users

What must be do to skip required Privacy policy or what can be write about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The additional permissions come from Google Play Services. There's currently a bug in version 12.0.0, the services add not needed permission to your app like READ_PHONE_STATE. If you are sure you won't need this permission you can strip them out from your apk using something like that in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
    tools:node="remove"/>
```